# Using fulltext @distance in PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search

I'm struggling with PDO prepared statements using the *@distance* operator with InnoDB table queries. A straight query would look something like this:

`MATCH (sText) AGAINST ('"tiger mouse" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

(Notice the nested single and double quotes in the syntax, with the distance operator outside the double quotes.) This yields the expected result, matching all instances of "tiger" and "mouse" at maximum four words distance. Now, a prepared statement like this fails (with no results):

`MATCH (sText) AGAINST (':words @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

If I remove the single quotes above, it fails with a syntax error. The above seems to be the only possible syntax with the operator not bound as a part of the `:words` variable.

Then, if I bind the distance operator along with the keywords, as `"tiger mouse" @4` (with or without surrounding single quotes) and simply use:

`MATCH (sText) AGAINST (:words IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

The "tiger mouse" is interpreted as a literal (matching only adjacent words) and `@4` is not interpreted as a distance operator, but as just another query word. Without the double quotes, the operator is again not interpreted, and matches are at any distance.

If I add single quotes around `':words'` with the operator bound as above, there are again no results.

I've double-checked that the bound data passed into prepare/execute is correct, and it's a bit of an impasse here. I hope this isn't as of yet unsupported by PDO. Anyone have leads on what manner of magic is required to get it working?

Comment: Very strange, I suppose `:word` as `"tiger mouse" @4` should work.

Comment: Try your third query with [`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php). I don't say it's a good solution. But I would like to know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Seems to [work](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWpFYDYMATvNuQvUKmB1H4/0) in plain SQL.

Comment: An interesting case. May I ask you to add an [MCVE](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) to your question?

Comment: Done; https://pastebin.com/47HAtcUh and it works OK. How peculiar that my original case is now also working as expected.  Must have been the MCVE-munching gremlins causing interference. `o_O` Thanks everyone!